# SQL Server database restore error

Tags: sql, sql-server, sql-server-2005, sql-server-2008, sql-server-2008r2-express

I am trying to restore a database on SQL Server 2005 but when I try to select the backuo location, I get the permissions error:

> TITLE: Locate Backup File -
>   SPARROW-VAIO\SQLEXPRESS05
>
> C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft SQL Server\MSSQL.2\MSSQL\Backup
>   Cannot access the specified path or file on the server. Verify that you
>   have the necessary security privileges and that the path or file exists.
>
> If you know that the service account can access a specific file,
>   type in the full path for the file in
>   the File Name control in the Locate
>   dialog box.

I am using SQL Server 2008 R2 Management Studio and login to Sql Server 2005 using windows authentication. I tried to create a user and when I go to user mapping, and tried to give access to model database, it says database not available. My SQL Server 2005 version is

```
Microsoft SQL Server 2005 - 9.00.1399.06 (Intel X86)   
Oct 14 2005 00:33:37   
Copyright (c) 1988-2005 Microsoft Corporation  
Express Edition on Windows NT 6.1 (Build 7600: )
```

Please suggest solution.

Answer (score 0):

the issue fixed when I run SQL server 2008 R2 as Administrator